# Atualizar campo de uma seleção de um array de objetos com filter

Tags: javascript, vuex

Tenho uma lista selecionada com alguns registros (não todos) e preciso aplicar uma atualização em campo específico da seleção mas nao quero repetir `arr.filter(x).filter(y).filter(z...)`

Em uma situação normal de apenas um registro eu faço assim no vue:

```
const obj = { 'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': false }

const resultado = {...obj, c: true}
```

e através de uma actions chamo uma mutation que atualiza a store:

```
export const ATUALIZAR_LOG = (state, resultado) => {

  const indice = state.logs.findIndex(c => c.id === resultado.id)
  state.logs.splice(indice, 1, resultado)
}
```

Mas, agora preciso atualizar uma seleção de um array:

```
const array = [  
    { 'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': false },  
    { 'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': false },  
    { 'id': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': false },  
    { 'id': 4, 'b': 2, 'c': false },  
    { 'id': 5, 'b': 2, 'c': false }  
]
```

Preciso atualizar o campo c com true das IDs (2 e 4) então quando o cliente seleciona as IDs 2 e 4 de uma lista eu recebo um array:

`let selecao = [2, 4] // resultado da seleção do cliente
const campo = { 'c': true } // campo que eu vou atualizar`

Se eu jogar direto a ID no filter até consigo exemplo:

```
let campo = { 'c': true }  
const resultado = array.filter(i => i.id === 3).map(o => Object.assign(o, campo))
```

ou mesmo chamando uma funcção:

```
function filtroChave (chave) {  
    if (chave.id === 2 || chave.id === 4 || ...) {  
        return true  
    }  
    return false  

}  

let campo = { 'c': true }  
const resultado = array.filter(filtroChave).map(o => Object.assign(o, campo))
```

O resultado esperado eu consigo mas, não quero lançar de forma estática até pq não sei quantos registros o usuário vai escolher além de ficar horrível de se vê.

Não gosto dos For* da vida mas até tentei um forIn sem sucesso.
Não tenho ideia de como ter esse resultado e mesmo tendo esse resultado não sei como atualizar a vueX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa o `reduce` e cria um novo array.

Veja se ajuda:

```js
const array = [
{ 'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': false },
{ 'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': false },
{ 'id': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': false },
{ 'id': 4, 'b': 2, 'c': false },
{ 'id': 5, 'b': 2, 'c': false }
];

let ids = [2, 4];

let result = array.reduce((acc, o) => acc.concat(ids.includes(o.id) ? Object.assign(o, { c: true }) : o), []);

console.log(result);

// ou
let result2 = array.reduce((acc, o) => {

    let obj = ids.includes(o.id) ? Object.assign(o, { c: true }) : o;

    acc.push(obj);

    return acc;

}, []);
```

Comment: O problema é que eu recebo uma matriz tipo [1, 5, 7, 11.....], eu nao tenho uma chave para identificar além disso nao posso fazer mutação diretamente na matriz pois o vueX reclama.

Comment: @sidiaracastro editei a resposta

Comment: Show meu amigo! Fiz uma pequena mudança para atender a minha necessidade e está funcionando sim como esperado. Muito obrigada.